# React setState with deep nesting using Object.assign and Lodash cloneDeep

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have a rather deep state structure (called `myObjects` in examples below).

This code works:

#### Example 1 (Object.assign)

```
import set from 'lodash/set'

changeObjectProperty = (key = '', path = '', value = null) => {
    const updatedMyObject = Object.assign({}, this.state.myObjects[key])
    set(updatedMyObject, path, value)
    const newMyObjects = Object.assign({}, this.state.myObjects, { [key]: updatedMyObject })
    this.setState({ myObjects: newMyObjects })
}
```

...but this is not a deep clone so I’m reusing references.

#### Example 2 (cloneDeep)

If I instead use `cloneDeep`:

```
import set from 'lodash/set'
import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep'

changeObjectProperty = (key = '', path = '', value = null) => {
    const updatedMyObject = cloneDeep(this.state.myObjects[key])
    set(updatedMyObject, path, value)
    const newMyObjects = Object.assign({}, this.state.myObjects, { [key]: updatedMyObject })
    this.setState({ myObjects: newMyObjects })
}
```

...React doesn’t seem to notice the state change. Why?

Also, the article [“Handling State in React: Four Immutable Approaches to Consider” (Cory Dash on Medium.com)](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5) says:

> “Deep cloning causes unnecessary renders since React thinks everything has changed when in fact perhaps only a specific child object has changed.”

...so maybe Example 1 with shallow merge is preferred?